# ¿Por qué no se ejecuta este código?, extension de firefox no funciona pero el código si funciona si lo pego en la consola

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-webextensions, dev-tools

Estoy haciendo una extensión de firefox, por ahora lo que quiero es obtener todas las peticiones que se hacen en el sitio web. Para ello modifiqué los metodos `open` y  `send` de `XMLHttpRequest`

Lo que no entiendo es por qué el código no se ejecuta, pero si lo copio y pego en la consola del navegador si funciona perfectamente.

aqui el código completo

**xhrScript.js**

```
(function(){

    const proxiedOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function ( _, url) {
        this.__URL = url;
        return proxiedOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    const proxiedSend = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
        const { protocol, host } = window.location;
        // showing only when it paste in console
        console.log("full request url ", `${protocol}//${host}${this.__URL}`);
        return proxiedSend.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));
    };

})();

// this works all times
document.body.style.border = "7px solid blue";
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "XHR request urls",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "get all the request url's",

    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["xhrScript.js"]
      }
    ]  
}
```

Como se puede notar, tengo una linea al final que cambia el border `document.body.style.border = "7px solid blue";` esto siempre funciona, pero el código que modifica los metodos de xhr no se ejecuta. Solo se ejecuta si lo copio y pego en la consola, allí si me da la url completa tal como quiero.

He probado con webs normales y tambien con SPA (Single Page Applications), con ambas sirve pero solo pegando el código en la consola.

Comment: Si pones un `console.log('Extensión aplicada')` dentro de la función *inline*, ¿no se muestra? Quizá tu error es asumir que se está usando XHR en lugar de `fetch`.

Comment: si se muestra, pero ya encontré la respuesta, tiene que ver con que las modificaciones a window en los scripts para hacer extensiones no influye en el window de la aplicación. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817357/11039931

Answer (score 0):

los scripts para las extensiones de firefox son "Content Scripts", los cuales no toman en cuenta directamente las modificaciones que se le hagan a el objeto window. Por ello hay que usar ciertas propiedades que trae dicho objeto window dentro de los "content_scripts"

dichas propiedades son `window.wrappedJSObject` y el método `window.exportFunction`
con estos dos se puede "exportar las modificaciones" que se le hagan a window.

aqui está mejor explicado modificando un poco mi ejemplo. (está en inglés ya que también hice la pregunta en inglés) [misma pregunta en inglés, con respuesta mejor explicada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817357/11039931)